# WPF Windows Service and UserControl not working together

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have an `UserControl` that converts user data into a `FlowDocument`.  The problem is in a `Windows Service visual C# application` this `UserControl` crashes.  It seems that the service does not like that the `UserControl` creates UI components.  How do I get around this?

I should note that this `UserControl` works perfectly in a WPF application.

Background:
The `UserControl` takes data and returns a `FlowDocument` that will be used for different things.  It does this by converting data elements into UI components.  For example, say there is `ObservableCollection` it will create a `Grid`, then add `ColumnDefinition` and `RowDefinition` as needed to the `Grid`.  As stated above this `UserControl` works perfectly in a WPF application.  If I call the `UserControl` from the Windows Service it will return this error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager..ctor()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.GetCurrentInputManagerImpl()
   at System.Windows.Input.KeyboardNavigation..ctor()
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.FrameworkServices..ctor()
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.EnsureFrameworkServices()
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement..ctor()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Control..ctor()
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl..ctor()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector..ctor()
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid..ctor()
```

I figured a way around this is to do the following:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(delegate
{
    MyControl con = new MyControl(myData);
});
```

Now it returns this error message:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I am at a loss and really do not want to do a re-write of this `UserControl`

Comment: Do you really need to use service for this? Most UI controls are not designed to work from services. Even if you manage to recreate more or less similar environment, you still won't be sure that everything will work correctly. And if you use them to generate some content/data, then there are usually better alternatives.

Comment: @Eugene Podskal  Yes I do.  The service does some processing then produce a report (based on the processes) and will be sent to the required user.

Comment: Perhaps there is a way to generate such reports without WPF controls?

Comment: In the worst case if there is no alternative to WPF and it turns impossible to use it from windows service, you may try to launch another application in interactive session to do the processing - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/winsdk/2009/07/14/launching-an-interactive-process-from-windows-service-in-windows-vista-and-later/

Comment: @EugenePodskal I have discovered when using a memory profiler the control will leak when generating images (which is what I am assuming you are  doing).  I have been able to get the control to finalize however there are other components that are generated by WPF that are not released.  High numbers of controls produces huge memory leaks.  Specifically related to the KeyboardNavigation. Have you been able to resolve those issues on your end and if so how?

Comment: @Mike Unfortunately, I am not the original poster (@Xaphann is), so I don't know how this problem got tackled down in the end. Also I have initially said that this approach doesn't look very reliable to me.

Comment: @EugenePodska  The base of this question deals more with me trying to re-use code and not completely re-writing something.  The end solution was to do something completely different